# Modifying Identity for oracle.security.idm.RoleProfile using setProperty method

Tags: java, oracle-fusion-middleware

In the [Oracle® Fusion Middleware Security Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10043/devuserole.htm) under the section Modifying an Identity, it is written:

> In order to modify an identity, you need a reference to the identity.
>   The User, UserProfile, Role, and RoleProfile classes provide the
>   following APIs to facilitate modifying identities:
>
> user.setProperty(ModProperty prop);   user.setProperties(ModProperty
>   [] props);
>
> ModProperty structure consists of:
>
> ```
> the field name
>
> its new value(s)
>
> the modifying operator
> ```
>
> Valid operators are:
>
> ModProperty.ADD ModProperty.REMOVE ModProperty.REPLACE
>
> In this example, a display name is replaced:
>
> UserProfile usrprofile = usr.getUserProfile();   ModProperty mprop =
>   new ModProperty(UserProfile.DISPLAY_NAME,    "modified display name", 
>   ModProperty.REPLACE);   usrprofile.setProperty(mprop);

But no sample is provided for the [oracle.security.idm.RoleProfile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e14658/oracle/security/idm/RoleProfile.html). Also this interface doesn't have the `setProperty(ModProperty mprop)` like [oracle.security.idm.UserProfile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e14658/oracle/security/idm/UserProfile.html#setProperty_oracle_security_idm_ModProperty_). So how do we change the property for this class?

Answer (score 1):

To use the `setProperty(ModProperty mprop)` method you need to cast the `RoleProfile` instance with the class `oracle.security.idm.providers.stdldap.LDRole`(I didn't find its documentation or javadoc). In-fact the interface `oracle.security.idm.RoleProfile` extends `oracle.security.idm.Role` and the abstract class `oracle.security.idm.spi.AbstractRoleProfile` implements it, which in turns is extended by following three classes:

1. `oracle.security.idm.providers.stdldap.LDRole`,
2. `oracle.security.idm.providers.libovd.LibOVDRole` and
3. `oracle.security.idm.util.RoleProfileValueObject`

All of them has `setProperty(ModProperty modProp)` method defined within themselves. Among them the `oracle.security.idm.util.RoleProfileValueObject` class throws `oracle.security.idm.OperationNotSupportedException` from `setProperty(ModProperty modProp)` method and it does not do anything.

So the solution is:

```
RoleProfile roleprofile = role.getRoleProfile();
ModProperty mprop = new ModProperty("someprop", "modified display name", ModProperty.ADD);
((LDRole)roleprofile).setProperty(mprop);
```

That's all folks. :)